# jQuery powered menu dosen't play well in android chrome

Tags: android, jquery, google-chrome, menu, slidedown

On this site http://creeight.se/stackExample1/ the vertical dropdown menu works in my desktop browsers (Chrome,FF,IE10) but it's really buggy in Chrome for android. The menu uses .slideDown() to open submenus.

You see the problem if you open: "Bloggen - arkiv" then "2014".

An interesting thing is that if you scroll the page just a little bit down, it suddenly looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it.

In my css I had overflow: hidden; on all my li tags. I removed it and now it works.